# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to upgrade spring 3 to spring 4.2.6. Below code is from `common-context.xml`

```
<bean id="jobRepository">   class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
        p:databaseType="oracle" p:dataSource-ref="appDataSource"
        p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager"
        p:isolationLevelForCreate="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
 </bean>
```

This is using `ParameterizedRowMapper` internally.  I am getting the below
error while running my batch job as

```
: Error creating bean with name
'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [common-context.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource
[common-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource
 [common-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository'
 while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource
 [common-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

Unable to resolve the error. Please help!

Comment: Probably you need to add spring-jdbc to your classpath

Comment: Let use see what are the jars and its versions you are using

Comment: I was using in compatible version of spring-batch-core and spring infrastructure.instead of using 3.0.0,i added the compatible version of 3.0.7.This solves the issue.Thanks Luca and Karthik for help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and fixed it using the lastest version of Spring Batch (3.0.7.RELEASE) and the latest version of Spring Batch Admin (1.3.1.RELEASE).

I'm using Spring 4.2.8.RELEASE